# What are the exact conditions for 1D elastic collisions? Is there a list for characterizing when elastic collisions occur?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision, material-science, elasticity

We know there are elastic, inelastic, and partially elastic collisions. In a fully elastic collision, both momentum and kinetic energy are fully conserved. However, that tells us nothing for *which* circumstances this occurs.

Initially, I thought the condition was that the two objects had to have been hard, like metal. However, when I tried to do collision experiments I found this was not the case, because the contact surface area of the objects in collision was very large. In other words, if your objects are hard, but they have large contact surface areas, they will not rebound and cause an elastic collision.

Also, there are cases where the object at contact does not have to be "hard." For example, many airtrack experiments have carts that have elastic strips attached to them, which also causes elastic collisions. Alternatively, we could have springs as well.

Currently, I have two cases in mind that I think guarantee elastic collisions:

1. There is a spring or band or elastic metal strip between the two objects (this is what you see in airtrack experiments).
2. The point of contact is a very small area between two hard surfaces (this is what you see when you collide balls in Newton's cradle).

Are there any other cases I'm missing? Is it possible to make an exhaustive list or is that impractical? More importantly, is there a simple characterization that obviates the need to make any such list?

I am aware of the *coefficient of restitution* $e$ and the fact that $e=1$ for elastic collisions, but my question is, what is it that determines $e=1$? Or if $e=1$ can only occur in ideal conditions, what is it that determines $e\approx 1$?

I would imagine there are two things we have to take into account:

- the materials of the objects, and
- the geometry of the objects.
  Based on those two things, could we determine $e\approx 1$? Is there some other factor as well?

(Note we can ask the same question for $e\approx 0$, and the answer turns out to be pretty easy. An inelastic collision occurs whenever the two objects end up moving together, either by sticking to each other with sticky tape, velcro, or by experiencing plastic deformation, or by friction of some sort. I find it interesting that there is no simple characterization like this for elastic collisions.)

Comment: What you are looking for is a dead end. We who have run demonstration labs before can tell you that you can just buy balls/beads of the same mass and size and essentially all the relevant parameters being the same, but one is very bouncy and the other is essentially not at all bouncy. There is no way to know which one you are holding until you try bouncing. The value is experimentally extracted, not predicted.

Comment: There are no elastic collisions at all. All real collisions are inelastic. Classical physics is simply a series of approximations. The case of elastic collisions is one of them. It makes life a lot easier... on paper.

Comment: @FlatterMann Well it's a good reminder, so I appreciate it. I can rephrase my question to ask for $e > 0.95$ instead of $e=1$ if you want.

Comment: There are no inelastic collisions with e>0.95 that are happening close to the speed of sound in materials, either. At most you can get them in collisions that are slow compared to the speed of sound. So now you would have to rephrase your question, yet again.

Comment: @FlatterMann Interesting. What about a collision between metal balls in Newton's cradle?

Comment: Might barely get you there, but only if it's very well made. There are no inelastic collisions in mechanical systems. That concept is merely one more approximations we make to simplify formulas.